# UITableView deselectRowAtIndexPath fades to white instead of contentView.backgroundColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have a tableview with a bunch of cells of various pretty colors. When I tap on one, it highlights fine, but when I call deselectRowsAtIndexPaths the fadeout animation goes from the highlighted color to white, not to the cell's contentView.backgroundColor. Any idea how to fix this? It looks really ugly with the cell fading from grey to white, then snapping to orange all of a sudden.

Comment: Can you post some code? Or even the cell screenshot in storyboard/nib?

Comment: @Mercurial, the only real code I use to modify the cell's appearance is cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor]; Is there something else I have to set to make the transition fluid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you set the backgroundColor on the cell itself and not its contentView.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured this out through some experimentation but I'm accepting your answer regardless. Thanks!